# Accessing attributes from another nested class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to achieve something similar to this construction:

```
class Outer:
    class A:
        foo = 1

    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            self.bar = A.foo

Outer.B().bar  # ==> 1
```

But this fails with

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

I'm not even sure I understand why as `A` is (I thought) in scope.

Could you help me clarify why this doesn't work and how I could get around it?

Comment: Nope, class scopes do not create enclosing scopes. That is why in a method you can use `A`, you would have to use `Outer.A`, as you'd have to in `B.__init__`. But why are you using nested classes to begin with? It's not a common pattern in Python... what *advantage* is it providing?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OK, I didn't realise that class scopes where different.I agree that this is not a very common pattern, and I only use it for the first time here, basically I have two very small helper classes (mainly "containers" for class attributes) and I don't think it is worth moving that to a module. Also, those two small classes are not intended to be part of the public interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names are looked up *only* in `globals`, `locals`, and nonlocal cells (but you don't have a closure here).

Write `Outer.A` instead of `A`, or consider making `Outer` a module.

Comment: Indeed, very simple, I initially thought that Outer would not be available as the class was not created yet.

Comment: `Outer` is not available for code executed at class scope. It *is* available for code executed at function scope, since the functions are only executed later. Note also that `__class__` exists, but it's mainly useful for `reload` or copy-pasted code to prevent typos.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use `Outer.A.foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Just like what you did for `Outer.B().bar`: do the same for `self.bar=Outer.A().foo`

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes in Python do not have acces to the members of the enclosing class. A is not in scope of B as you state. A and B are both in scope of Outer, but they do not know of each other. Therefore a possible solution to your problem:

```
class Outer:
    class A:
        foo = 1

    class B:
        def __init__(self, class_a):
            self.bar = class_a.foo

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = self.A()
        self.b = self.B(self.a)


print(Outer.A.foo) # 1
print(Outer.B.bar) # AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute 'bar'

outer = Outer()
print(outer.a.foo)  # 1
print(outer.b.bar)  # 1
```